# WebView vs TextView for displaying html content

Tags: javascript, android, css, webview, textview

I have a number of html pages as Strings in my android app. So you might visualize it as `List<String> myWebPages` where each webpage is an html page equipped with css and javascript and html body. What is the best way to display these web pages to user? Should I use WebView or should I use a TextView? Notice that I don't have urls for the WebView; how would I pass the String? As for the TextView, can it handle full web pages with css and javascript?

**Update**

When I use

```
webView.loadData(Html.fromHtml(value).toString(), "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

my code is a pile of non-sense; it does not interpret the css etc well apparently.

For completeness, here is my html code (template in any case)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <link href="/stylesheets/shCore.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="/js/style/shThemeDefault.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="/js/shCore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/shAutoloader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/shBrushPython.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/shBrushJava.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    SyntaxHighlighter.all();



    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <script src="/js/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <style>

        .syntaxhighlighter .toolbar {
        background-color: #ffffff !important;
        color: #ffffff !important;
        }

        .syntaxhighlighter .toolbar a,.syntaxhighlighter .toolbar a:hover {
        background-color: #ffffff !important;
        color: #ffffff !important;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

<pre class='brush:java'>my java code in here </pre>

</body>
</html>
```

By the way, I am not a web developer so the html is my best effort (if you find mistakes)

Comment: A TextView is for displaying Text, with the caveat that you can add simple icons to the Text. Past that, it has no way of interpreting or displaying HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I use WebView or should I use a TextView?

Since `TextView` has no support for CSS or JavaScript, you have no choice but to use `WebView`.

> Notice that I don't have urls for the WebView; how would I pass the String?

Call `loadData()` on the `WebView`, passing the HTML.

Comment: @KatedralPillon: "my code is a pile of non-sense; it does not interpret the css etc well apparently" -- you are using relative URLs to CSS. At best, this might work if you use `loadDataWithBaseURL()` to say what those relative URLs are relative to.

Comment: Thanks. I have done so with `webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(url,value, "text/html", "UTF-8",url);` and the content is now showing but without any of the css applied.