# CSS not applying in android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, css, android-layout, webview

This is a followup question to [WebView vs TextView for displaying html content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37007443/webview-vs-textview-for-displaying-html-content)

Here is the code

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(url,value, "text/html", "UTF-8",url);
```

And here is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <link href="/stylesheets/shCore.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="/js/style/shThemeDefault.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="/js/shCore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/shAutoloader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/shBrushPython.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/shBrushJava.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    SyntaxHighlighter.all();



    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <script src="/js/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <style>

        .syntaxhighlighter .toolbar {
        background-color: #ffffff !important;
        color: #ffffff !important;
        }

        .syntaxhighlighter .toolbar a,.syntaxhighlighter .toolbar a:hover {
        background-color: #ffffff !important;
        color: #ffffff !important;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

<pre class='brush:java'>my java code in here </pre>

</body>
</html>
```

The CSS is not taking effect as the code is not highlighted. How might I fix this?

Comment: Where do you have your scripts ? `src="/js/shCore.js"` will not work as-is. You need to put them in your project's assets directory, and reference them with something like `src="file:///android_asset/myscript.js"`. You can also have them on the web somewhere, and reference them with something like `src="http://yourwebsite.com/myscript.js"`. I hope I understand your question right ?

Comment: I will try both, and see if they work.

Comment: Sorry I had one error in my code and I corrected it. Ref `webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(url,value, "text/html", "UTF-8",url);`. So the `url` parameter is supposed to do what you are suggesting.

Comment: What is the the url parameter ? Local file ? Http address ? If it's a http address, have you added internet permission to your app's manifest ? if it's a local file, have you added access storage permission ? If it's in an asset, are you using the same directory structure ?

Comment: http address (base, such as `http://www.google.com`)

Comment: In that case, I don't know what else could be wrong, sorry.